# I need help getting an object to cover the corners of the webpage

Tags: html, css

Below are the pictures of my heading element

h1 element

[image]

h1 element inspected

[image]

```
html,body {

box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {

 box-sizing: inherit;

text-align: left;
}

h1, footer{

margin-top: 0;

padding: 2%;

background-color: #CEF9F6;

}

h1{

background-image: url(“headerbg.gif”);

background-position: center;

background-size: cover;

box-shadow: 0.01cm .19cm 1.7em;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [take tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, [post a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0):

Give this too

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
* , *:before *:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
*
{
margin:0;
padding:0
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Here " * " means to apply all.

Answer (score -2):

use this

```
*{
 box-sizing: border-box; 
 margin:0; 
 padding:0;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, could you please explain your answer and how it helps solve the problem.